# Print out in custom paper size in C# aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

What would the best way to print from asp.net so that details on a web form will be printed from a printer in card size - which is 14cm tall and 10cm wide? 
What I really want is a custom paper size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeez no responses. I had to print using Java script win print function and then set the printer default size to 10cm by 14cm. Job done!